# While manipulating MM/DD/YYYY format, how to get the month (All #'s before the dash)

Tags: java, regex, string, int

I'm working on a calendar app and I already have a Hashmap set up so that each month corresponds to an integer. In my program, the user will enter a date value using a `datePicker` node. The `datePicker` will give one of two formats:

`MM/DD/YYYY`  as in 11/13/18  (November)

or

`M/DD/YY`  as in 1/13/18 (January)

Using `datePicker.toString();`, how would I get the month of the chosen date? I will need to compare it to the String values for error checking.

---

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> monthHashMap = new HashMap();
private void HashTable(){
    monthHashMap.put(1, "January");
    monthHashMap.put(2, "February");
    monthHashMap.put(3, "March");
    monthHashMap.put(4, "April");
    monthHashMap.put(5, "May");
    monthHashMap.put(6, "June");
    monthHashMap.put(7, "July");
    monthHashMap.put(8, "August");
    monthHashMap.put(9, "September");
    monthHashMap.put(10, "October");
    monthHashMap.put(11, "November");
    monthHashMap.put(12, "December");

}
```

Comment: If this is a toy example to understand HashMaps and RegEx then ok, but if this a snippet of an application. I recommend using java.time class, as time and dates are a bane for developers. Best to not reinvent the wheel. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

As a question of string manipulation, the easiest thing code be to split the string at `'/'` characters, convert the first element of the resulting array to an integer, and (supposing you want the month name) look up the result in your map:

```
String monthName = monthHashMap.get(Integer.valueOf(datePicker.toString().split("/")[0]));
```

You could allow that to be shortcut a bit by using numeric strings instead of integers as map keys.  Alternatively, perhaps your `datePicker` can provide the selected date in a form that facilitates another approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the month of the date, which for my example, the date would be `01/02/0003`, now, to get the month of that date, you can use the `String#substring` method.

```java
String month = datePicker.toString().substring(0, 2); // getting the month.
```

Then like [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) said, use `Integer#valueOf`, like this:

```
String monthName = monthHashMap.get(Integer.valueOf(month));
```

Which will return `January`.